# javascript: cancel submit

Tags: javascript, forms, submit, form-submit

I need to stop the submit button from submitting the form...  I used `return false` to do it and it worked perfectly until I introduced `charAt()` to return the first character. Once I did, the submit button started to submit the form again. Here is the code:

```
<form id="pathfinder" method="post">
<input type="text" id="sum1"> 
<input type="text" id="sum2">
<input type="text" id="sum3">
<input type="submit" onclick="return total()" value="Get Total">

<div id="display" style="height: 50px; width: 100%;"></div>

<script>
function total(){
    var a = document.forms["pathfinder"]["sum1"].value || 0;
    var b = document.forms["pathfinder"]["sum2"].value || 0;
    var c = document.forms["pathfinder"]["sum3"].value || 0;
    var d = c.charAt(0)
    //alert(a+b)
    var display=document.getElementById("display")
    display.innerHTML=d;
  return false
}
<\script>
```

Comment: Move the listener to the form's submit handler. The form can be submitted without clicking the button.

Answer (score 1):

sum3 is proabaly empty so c is 0. 0 is not a string, so when you call `charAt` on it an error is raised.

You could use `String(c).charAt(0)` to make sure c is a string, or just use `'0'` (0 as a string) as the default value for a,b and c instead of `0`.

Answer (score 0):

It stopped working because script throws an error. You can't call `charAt` on the number - what happens if input left empty and then `c` it defaults to `0`:

```
var c = document.forms["pathfinder"]["sum3"].value || 0;
```

You can simply verify that you call `charAt` on string by wrapping `c` into `String` function, casting number `0` to string `"0"`:

```
var d = String(c).charAt(0);
```

One more thing: it's `</script>`, not `<\script>`.

Comment: Thanks ma, it worked and yeah thanks for the heads up for </script>